# Bootstrap Radiobuttons Active Colour Change

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap kit for altering the style of the radio buttons along with AngularJS however I am running into an issue where colors are concerned. The problem I am facing is the following:

I found this code snippet to alter the color of the chosen (active) radio button

```
    .btn.active, .btn:active {
        background-color: #XXXXXX;
    }
```

However, I believe due to posting the style of the active button is not being persisted. The code used for the button group is the following:

```
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
         <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="opt_ord" ng-model="content" value="1">Ord
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
                 <input type="radio" name="options" id="opt_int1" ng-model="content" value="2">Int (1)
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
                  <input type="radio" name="options" id="opt_int2" ng-model="content" value="3">Int (2)
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
                  <input type="radio" name="options" id="opt_adv1" ng-model="content" value="4">Adv (1)
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
                  <input type="radio" name="options" id="opt_adv2" ng-model="content" value="5">Adv (2)
      </label>
   </div>
```

Any input on how I can keep the button active (even when the post occurs) would be greatly appreciated.By persisting the color I mean that the button behaves like a toggle button, "feels pressed down/stands out from the rest". Thanks!

Comment: Not completely sure what you're asking. Here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/c3agm0ck/) though.

Comment: I want exactly what you did there, and funnily enough used the same code as you did. The problem is that whenever the radio button is checked, some content on the screen is being updated, causing a post (I think). So when this occur, the page is refreshed and the buttons are set to default once again. What I need now is to persist the color through the refreshing.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly I think you would need to apply the `.active` class to the `<label>` that contains the selected radio button (using javascript).

Comment: I conducted further testing and I realized that the problem is not with the AngularJS, but with the CSS itself. The same code on the JSFiddle does not work locally.